# Error:page.evaluate: Target closed in playwright

Tags: javascript, reactjs, playwright, playwright-test

I want to get the web vital performance of **Cumulative Layout Shift** using [**layout instability.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Layout_Instability_API), I have written a playwright test case for it but when executed its throws the timeout exceeded and page.evaluate error.

```
test.only('CLS', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto(HOME_PAGE_URL, { waitUntil: 'networkidle' });
  const cummulativeLayoutShift = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const observer = new PerformanceObserver((list) => {
        const result = list.getEntries();
        resolve(result);
      });
      observer.observe({ type: 'layout-shift', buffered: true });
    });
  });
  console.log(`SHIFT - ${cummulativeLayoutShift}`);
});
```

Comment: This code looks correct. Could you be hitting the timeout because you're waiting for the network to become quiet? Do other tests succeed waiting for `networkidle`?

Comment: other tests passes waiting for networkidle